# Duplicates in Realm for UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have two classes and one of them has a relation to another:

```
public FirstClass
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Age {get; set;}
}
```

and another class where I use this realm object like this for the to-many relationship:

```
public OtherClass 
{
    public IList<FirstClass> From {get; set;}
    public IList<FirstClass> To {get; set;}
}
```

my Problem is that for each saving of a new OtherClass the FirstClass is also saved as a new one. But I want that if the same FirstClass is saved that it has a link to the saved one and no duplicate is created.
Is that possible? And if yes how?

Comment: add more code where you are writing objects.
BTW you need to run a query if that record already present in db don't add otherwise add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FirstClass` doesn't have a primary key defined, so there's no way for Realm to know that you want an existing instance. You can add a primary key on `FirstClass` and then do something like:

```
public FirstClass : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Other properties
}

var otherClass = ...;
realm.Write(() =>
{
    realm.Add(otherClass, update: true);
});
```

Comment: That means that I need to check each realm object in the database if the new object with the same properties is in there already. Is that right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - you can use `realm.Add(firstClass, update: true)` which will then update all properties of the existing object to match the object you're adding. If no object exists, it will add the new object.